# PyQt program randomly not responding without a Traceback

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wrote a program to batch change the filenames of many pictures, using PyQt5.

When I run it, it runs through some pictures successfully, and randomly crash without a Python Traceback, showing "has stopped working" in windows 8.1. Even if I use the same testcases, the program will sometimes crash after 20+ pictures, sometimes only 2, sometimes runs to the end.

I don't even know the program crashed in which line. How do I solve this problem?

Here is the program, I minimized the code that still work, and randomly crash as before.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import re
from PyQt5 import Qt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application_Variable = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow_Widget
    from FileName import Ui_FileName_Widget

class filename_class: # just a class to get path, filename, append
    def __init__(self, fullpath):

        self.re_path_temp = re.match(r".+/", fullpath)
        self.path = self.re_path_temp.group(0)
        self.name = fullpath[len(self.path):]
        self.append = self.name[len(self.name[:self.name.rfind('.')])-len(self.name)+1:]


class fileNameDefine_Widget(Qt.QWidget): # the rename widget
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(fileNameDefine_Widget, self).__init__()
        self.fileWidget = Ui_FileName_Widget()
        self.fileWidget.setupUi(self)

        self.filename = filename
        self.file_append = filename_class(self.filename).append # get the append

        self.fileWidget.InputFileName_LineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.input_file_name_Change)

    def input_file_name_Change(self):
        self.export_name = self.fileWidget.InputFileName_LineEdit.text() + "." + self.file_append
        self.fileWidget.ExportFileName_LineEdit.setText(self.export_name)
        self.fileWidget.InputFileName_LineEdit.setEnabled(True)


class MainWindow_Class(Qt.QWidget): # the main widget

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow_Class, self).__init__()

        self.main = Ui_MainWindow_Widget()  # init
        self.main.setupUi(self)
        self.root_directory = r"D:\TLCTest"
        self.file_list = Qt.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(caption="Select file", directory=self.root_directory)[0]

        self.count = 0 # count which file are being processed

        self.show()
        self.initiate_change_filename()

    def initiate_change_filename(self):
        file = self.file_list[self.count]

        # show the picture
        self.pixmap = Qt.QPixmap()
        self.pixmap.load(file)
        self.graphicsPixmapItem = Qt.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pixmap)
        self.graphicsScene = Qt.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsScene.addItem(self.graphicsPixmapItem)
        self.main.graphicsView.setScene(self.graphicsScene)

        # start the rename widget
        self.fileName_Widget = fileNameDefine_Widget(file)
        self.fileName_Widget.fileWidget.InputFileName_LineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.submit) # press enter to submit

        self.fileName_Widget.show()

    def submit(self):

        filename = self.fileName_Widget.filename
        path = filename_class(filename).path
        final_name = self.fileName_Widget.fileWidget.ExportFileName_LineEdit.text()

        os.rename(filename, path + final_name)
        self.count += 1

        if self.count == len(self.file_list):
            exit()
        else:
            self.fileName_Widget.close()
            self.initiate_change_filename()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_Qt_Program = MainWindow_Class()

    my_Qt_Program.show()
    sys.exit(application_Variable.exec_())
```

Comment: If you found debugging difficult, imagine how much harder it's going to be for people *who can't even see your code*.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have tested all the commented code without affecting the problem. There are more than 600 lines. I thought this is easier.

Comment: Easier for who? You need to create a small, self-contained, runnable example that reproduces the problem. Nine times out of ten, doing that will probably reveal the cause of the problem anyway.

Comment: @ekhumoro Apologize for my ignorance. I have edit the problem and posted a minimized 100 line example (before I posted this problem) .

Comment: That is not really a minimal example. And what is `override_graphicsScene`? Anyway, I would suggest that the problem is caused because you call `initiate_change_filename()` every time you process a file. This will create the graphics scene and the input dialog over and over again. Instead, create them *once*, and then re-configure them for each file.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry, forget to change that. I have used original Qt.QGraphicsScene to replace it. I will try your suggesstion.

Comment: @ekhumoro Seems like the problem was solved! After I "create the input dialog once, and then re-configure them for each file." Thank you very much~~

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As ekhumoro's comment, this problem was caused by repeatedly creating a `fileNameDefine_Widget` object like:

```
def initiate_change_filename(self):
    self.fileName_Widget = fileNameDefine_Widget(file)
```

Instead, one should create this object once, and **init** it every time required, like:

```
class TLC_processor_Class(Qt.QWidget):

    def init(self):
        # Blabla
        self.fileName_Widget = fileNameDefine_Widget(file)

    def initiate_change_filename(self):
        self.fileName_Widget.__init__(file)
```

Comment: but this doesn't answer why it won't print out the traceback? because i was having the same problem but different cases